# Image of application f defined on $R_3[X]$ as : $f(P)=P′+(X^2+2)P′′(X)$ (is my solution correct)?

Tags: vector-spaces

This is what I did:
Let $P(X) = a + bX + cX^2 + dX^3$.
$f(X) = \text{ ... } = 6dX^3 + \left(2c + 3d\right)X^2 + 2(6d+c)X + 4c + b$.
$f(X) = a(0,0,0,0) + b(1,0,0,0) + c(4,2,2,0) + d(0,12,3,6)$.
Is that even correct? Makes sense to me.
It should also be a linearly independent spanning set, I believe. It seems clear that no one vector can be written as a linear combination of any subset of the others, which I take to be the definition of a linearly independent spanning set.
Which led me to conclude that : $\text{Im}(f) = \text{span}\left\lbrace (1,0,0,0),(4,2,2,0),(0,12,3,6)\right\rbrace$.
Is that...correct?
Does that mean that : $\text{dim Im}(f) = 3$ ?
Thank you for the time you take to read/answer this.